# Force Landscape iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation

I am looking to have one view in my app have landscape orientation. I have managed to get the view to stay in landscape when rotated manually, but if the device is already portrait, it stays portrait, regardless of its supported orientation (set using `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method) . Is there a way to get the view to rotate automatically? I have tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS 6 force device orientation to landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by overriding `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` but in order for that to be called the viewController has to be **presented** (as in modal) and not pushed as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12897383/1262527):

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    NSLog(@" preferred called");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

In order to present your viewController in a UINavigationController use:

```
UINavigationController *presentedNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:protraitViewController];

[self presentViewController:presentedNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

To make UINavigationController respect your current viewController's orientation preferences use this simple [category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12539784/1262527) instead of sub-classing.

Also, this [part](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) of Apple's documentation is a good read for understanding iOS orientation handling better.

Comment: I found this question to be similar with a slightly different answer that apparently worked for a lot of people http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640870/ios-6-force-device-orientation-to-landscape?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Define the following in the UIViewController for your landscape-only view:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; } // or right or both
```

This should prevent your view from ever appearing in portrait.  From iOS documentation:

> **Declaring a Preferred Presentation Orientation** 
>   When a view controller
>   is presented full-screen to show its content, sometimes the content
>   appears best when viewed in a particular orientation in mind. If the
>   content can only be displayed in that orientation, then you simply
>   return that as the only orientation from your
>   `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method.

Comment: I have done this already using: `return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight| UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;` in my code. Sorry I forgot to include it in my question

Comment: This will never call. Please check.